# Is there something like log4j for bash?

Tags: bash, logs

Is there something like `log4j` for bash script? I would like to be able to treat errors differently based on their severity. For example, `log4j` allows me to differentiate between errors, info, debug, etc. Is there a way I can do that for bash?

I know, I can just write a function , that write to log as the following example:

```
LOG ()  { 
           echo `date` $* >> /var/log/my_log.log 
        }
```

But actually I want to know if something like log4j is relevant for bash

in order to get the ability for – **error level** and etc

Comment: What does log4j do? If you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j), which part of its feature set do you want?

Comment: I want to control the log sevirity as , errors , info , debug , etc , log4j enable that , and what I asked if there are something for bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most systems have the `logger` utility, which knows how to talk to `syslogd`. It allows you to set log level (severity), facility name, specify the log file to write to, send to `syslogd` on a remote host, write messages to `STDERR` as well as to the system log.

The logging semantics are not quite the same as those provided by tools like `log4j`, but by combining the `facility.level` settings with message tags, you can achieve something very close.

*Examples*

*NOTE:* These examples use the FreeBSD version of `logger`. Your system may have different options, so read your local documentation!

```
logger -p local3.info -f /var/log/messages -t MY_LOG_TAG "something interesting happened"
```

This will send the message to be logged in `/var/log/messages` with a severity of `info`, in the `local3` facility. It includes a tag (`-t MY_LOG_TAG`), which is included in each line. Tags are useful for extracting log entries with `grep`, `awk`, etc.

```
logger -h loghost -p mail.crit -s -f /var/log/mail "an unrecoverable error has occurred"
```

This one sends the message with severity `crit` in the `mail` facility to the remote machine `loghost`, to be logged in `/var/log/mail`. The `-s` causes the message to be printed on the the script's `STDERR` as well as sending it to be logged.

Comment: can you please provide example how to write to  some log by logger command ,

Comment: Does this have anything to do with bash errors? As far as I know, `logger` communicates with `syslog` which has nothing to do with bash errors.

Comment: @terdon - I interpreted the question as wanting a logging tool for use in bash scripts. `logger` is suitable for that, but if the question is specific to logging errors from `bash` itself, then no - `logger` won't work, and the question needs to be updated to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

There's good amount of detail on logging for shell scripts via global
varaibles of shell. We can emulate the similar kind of logging in shell
script: http://www.cubicrace.com/2016/03/log-tracing-mechnism-for-shell-scripts.html

The post has details on introdducing log levels like INFO , DEBUG, ERROR.
Tracing details like script entry, script exit, function entry, function exit.

Sample Log:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at my logging implementation on GitHub:

https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh

It supports five log levels (ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, and VERBOSE) as well as multiple loggers.